# 2 floated divs with first div width 100%

Tags: css, html, css-float, width

I have 2 divs floated left in a container div. The second div has `width: 20px`. I need the first div to fill all the available space and remains inline. Set first div width to 100% doesn't work because the second div with fixed width goes down. How can i do?

The code is described here: http://jsfiddle.net/7EW5h/4/

Thanks

Comment: do you know the size of the container?

Comment: I don't understand you question, do you want the first div to take up the full space, or the full space MINUS the 20px?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calc` CSS3 function and set a dynamic width to `#inner1` div as follows:

```
width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

It will be compatible with Firefox 16 (or later) and Internet Explorer 9 (or later).

You can add vendor prefixes as shown:

```
width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

To make it compatible with Chrome 19 (or later), Firefox 4 (or later), Internet Explorer 9 (or later) and Safari 6 (or later).

You can check compatible tables here: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Regarding to you example, I had to set `border: 0` to `#inner1` and `#inner2` divs.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested and worked out a solution in Chrome, IE9, Firefox and Opera:

1. Use containers for the two input elements.
2. Change the order of the elements so that the *right* one is *first*.
3. Do not float the element that is supposed to fill the remaining space, just set the `display` to `block` (which is the default for `div` elements).
4. Set the `margin-right` of the larger container to the total width of the right element. Here we also need to account for things like borders, margins and paddings of both elements.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner2">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div id="inner1">
        <input />
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#inner2 {
    float: right;
}
#inner2 input {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#inner1 {
    margin-right: 24px;
}
#inner1 input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7EW5h/22/.
Also note that i have explicitly set borders on the two `input` elements.

I can not get it to work without changing the HTML or the order of the two elements without using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `position:absolute;` to position the elements as you need?

See fiddle - [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wuVfG/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, without complicating things, you can do the following.

1. ​Remove the floats from the two inputs.
2. Absolutely position the second input as shown below.
3. add padding-right to the first input to avoid content overlap.
   also, even if it is not shown in my code below, don't forget the presence of default border, margin and    padding.​ ​

   ```
          #container {
              overflow: hidden;
              background-color: red;
           }

                  #inner1 {
                     width: 100%;
                      background-color: blue;
                      padding-right:45px;

                    }

                #inner2 {
                   height: 20px;
                   width: 20px;
                    background-color: green;
                    position:absolute;
                    right:0;
                    top:0;
                    }
   ```

   ​